# Inserting a whitspace character in a H2 database

Tags: java, sql, jpa, whitespace, h2

I want to store a character entity in a H2 database. An attribute of this letter entity is a Java character object.

Everything's working out as expected. I just have the problem that I can't get it to insert an entity with a whitespace character (' ' ASCII code 32dec) using Java PreparedStatement. Somehow a trim is always called on the input string when inserting, resulting in the character being stored as '' in the database.

My insert code looks like this:

```java
PreparedStatement statement =
             context.getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into DLM.ALPHABET_CHARACTER"
                 + " (ID, KEYBOARD_POSITION, SORT_POSITION, UNICODE_CHAR, PRODUCT_FAMILY)"
                 + " values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
statement.setLong(1, character.getId());
statement.setInt(2, character.getKeyboardPosition());
statement.setInt(3, character.getSortPosition());
statement.setString(4, String.valueOf(character.getUnicodeChar()));
statement.setString(5, alphabet.getProductFamily().name());
statement.execute();
```

Java generates the following SQL query from it:

```sql
insert into DLM.ALPHABET_CHARACTER (ID, KEYBOARD_POSITION, SORT_POSITION, UNICODE_CHAR, PRODUCT_FAMILY) 
values(0, 0, 0, ' ','PRODUCTA');
```

For higher Ascii characters, e.g. 鼾, this becomes:

```sql
insert into DLM.ALPHABET_CHARACTER (ID, KEYBOARD_POSITION, SORT_POSITION, UNICODE_CHAR, PRODUCT_FAMILY) 
values(0, 0, 0, STRINGDECODE('\u9f3e'),'PRODUCTA');
```

Edit:

I found out the following:

- If I execute the insert with Java I always get an empty cell field.
  Independent of whether I use ' ' or STRINGDECODE('\u0020')
- If I
  manually execute the insert for the whitespace character (using the
  h2 connection of my IDE) and use STRINGDECODE('\u0020'), everything
  works fine
- If I manually execute it with ' ' it also leads to a empty
  cell field

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Enity code:

```java
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Table(name = "alphabet_character")
public class AlphabetCharacterEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "localCounter")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "localCounter",
      strategy = "LocalCounterGenerator")
  private Long id;

  private Integer keyboardPosition;

  private Integer sortPosition;

  private Character unicodeChar;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ProductFamily productFamily;
}
```

JPA is generating the following SQL database for this entity:

```sql
create table dlm.alphabet_character (id bigint not null, keyboard_position integer, 
product_family varchar(255), sort_position integer, unicode_char char(255),
 primary key (id));
```

Comment: But `STRINGDECODE('\u0020')` *is* the [single space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm). The INSERT is correct. And I doubt that H2 trims `' '` to `''`.

Comment: I didn't believe that either, but I tested it with queries on the H2 database. If you send the query using `INSERT INTO DLM.ALPHABET_CHARACTER (ID, KEYBOARD_POSITION, SORT_POSITION, UNICODE_CHAR, PRODUCT_FAMILY) values(0, 0, 0, ' ','FAMILYA');` and then call a `SELECT CONCAT('a',UNICODE_CHAR, 'b') FROM DLM.ALPHABET_CHARACTER WHERE ID = 0;`, only "ab" will come out.

Comment: It seems to be a general behavior of H2 that trailing spaces are ignored. But how do I disable it?